# How to pass stateParams to the angular controller?

Tags: angularjs

I try to define stateParams in the controller, but it returns me an empty object {}

My app.js:

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ui.router','ngResource'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url:'/',
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/header.html'
                },
                'messages': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/messages.html',
                    controller  : 'MessageController'
                },
                'chat': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/chat.html',
                    controller  : 'ChatController'
                },
                'footer': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/footer.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.chat', {
            url: ':id'
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
```

My controller.js:

```
angular.module('testApp')

.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope,$stateParams) {

    $scope.chosenMessage = $stateParams;

}]);
```

And my template:

```
        <div ui-view="messages" class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div ui-view="chat" class="col-xs-6"></div>
```

I need an id from StateParams to define choosen message and chat content for the message.

Comment: use $state.params , or $stateParams.id

Comment: @Rejs $state.params does not work, and $stateParams.id return undefined

Comment: <a ui-sref="chat({ id: id})"> , u set like this

Comment: @Rejs if I have already set ui-sref="app.chat({id: mes.id})"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:
I have defined $state instead of $stateParams, and check for $state.params.id to get current state.